# Unable to view executed cell code in Spyder's IPython console

Tags: ipython, spyder

Whenever I am executing a code in Spyder, instead of showing the lines which I have ran in work environment  *(as in YouTube)*, its reflecting as runfile(c/user/...) or runcell(0,c/user/...) *(the actual issue)* in IPython console

Runfile and runcell screenshot

[image]

How to view as it shown in YouTube one?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please embed the image in your post instead of linking.

Comment: I guess they copy and paste the code to the console prompt instead of running a script from a file. Could you provide a link to the YouTube video?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) The answer to your question is in the question I referenced above.

Comment: Its been resolved @CarlosCordoba... your suggestion on setting, worked...
thank you very much..

Comment: No problem. I'm glad to hear it was useful for you.